# How to popup in the same window?

Tags: php, forms, popup, contacts

I have set the `<form action="sendemail.php">`. The below code is written in the `sendemail.php`.
The problem is that I want the status message be popped up in the same window say `contact.html`. It should not open a new window which says:

***"Thank you for contacting us. As early as possible  we will contact you"***

It comes in a new blank window with this message `^^^^`.

---

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$status = ("Thank you for contacting us. As early as possible  we will contact you"
);


$name        = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$email       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$product_id  = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['product_id']));
$phonenumber = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['phonenumber']));
$quantity    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['quantity']));
$subject     = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message     = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

$email_from = $email;
$email_to = 'xyz@gmail.com';

$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Product Id: ' . $product_id . "\n\n" . 'Contact Number: ' . $phonenumber . "\n\n" .'Quantity: ' . $quantity . "\n\n" .'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Complete Address: ' . $message ."\n\n";

$success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

echo json_encode($status);
die;
```

Comment: What do you mean with a popup in the same window? I'm guessing it's either an html element that looks like a popup, or you already have another popup for contact.html, which you want to update?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are doing `jSON`, but if `jSON` not required:

```
<?php
$name           =   @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$email          =   @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$product_id     =   @trim(stripslashes($_POST['product_id']));
$phonenumber    =   @trim(stripslashes($_POST['phonenumber']));
$quantity       =   @trim(stripslashes($_POST['quantity']));
$subject        =   @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message        =   @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

$email_from     =   $email;
$email_to       =   'xyz@gmail.com';

$body           =   'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Product Id: ' . $product_id . "\n\n" . 'Contact Number: ' . $phonenumber . "\n\n" .'Quantity: ' . $quantity . "\n\n" .'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Complete Address: ' . $message ."\n\n";

// If main processes successfully, then continue with message    
if(@mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>')) { ?>
    <!-- Just write normally -->
    Thank you for contacting us. As early as possible  we will contact you.
<?php die; } ?>
```